# Compiling with MinGW crashes while Cygwin works

Tags: c++, cygwin, mingw, ncurses, curses

I'm writing a simple roguelike, and I was compiling statically to test, but I found that the program a) crashes when input is given, and b) does not seem to randomize at all when I compiled with MinGW. I switched over to Cygwin to check it out, and found that the statically-compiled version with Cygwin performed exactly as expected. I used the same commands for both: `g++ -c FILE_NAME -std=c++14 -lncurses` for each source file, then `g++ -static -o dngn OBJECTS -std=c++14 -lncurses` to link the final build.

The MinGW build:
[mingw.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JlYH.png)

The Cygwin build:
[cygwin.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfyf6.png)

Both images are screengrabs of it running with the respective compiler

Comment: They say a picture is worth a thousand words, but it's not a replacement for your actual code. Take some time and put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. It's often something simple like an uninitialized variable that you may find while trying to find the problem spot. You could also consider using a debugger which will tell you exactly where the crash is and allow you to examine what's going on at the time of the crash.

Comment: The problem is, the same code works perfectly on Ubuntu and Cygwin, and not on MinGW. I don't even know how to start reducing it down. Are there any common things that cause defects of the <random> header/segfaults only in MinGW?

Comment: Yes, undefined behavior or differences in implementation defined behavior. A debugger is your best bet.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run `gdb`, even with a breakpoint at the beginning of `main`, it simply shows the same screen in mingw.png, and freezes.

Comment: This cannot be answered reasonable without code. Hence again, please, provide a [mcve]. If your code is too large you should reduce it until it contains the only necessary lines to reproduce your issue. Concerning this, [E. Lippert: How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is worth reading.

Comment: Does it works if you remove `--static` ? I noticed in the past that g++ and static are not always handling well some type of exception.

Comment: Try rebuilding everything with -Wall -Wextras --pedantic -O2. Get rid of all the warnings (really, all of them!). Try on all platforms. Note any version differences between your compilers in each platform.